# Dynamically changing the width of an HTML element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the width of a `li` element on hover using jQuery

```
echo"<div id='film_container'><ul>";
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
extract($row);
echo"<a href='#'><li class='film_list'> <img class='poster' src='$poster_small'/>      
<span>$film_name</span></li></a>";
}
echo"</ul></div>";
```

here is jquery

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('li .film_list').hover(function(){
 $(this).css("width","180px");
 });
 });
 </script>
```

here jquery css method is not working can anyone, any suggestions?

Comment: You should post the rendered HTML, not the PHP, as the PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: Remove the `PHP` stuff and leave just the `HTML` markup rendered. Also a bit of indentation to your code would help.

Comment: Why JQuery? Css handles hover: `li.film_list:hover { width: 180px; }`

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Just saying you are trying to do something and posting some code does not outline a problem or ask a question

Comment: apologies, this was my first question on this platform. i m new to both coding and stack.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('li.film_list').hover(function(){
 $(this).css("width","180px");
 });
 });
</script>
```

remove space in selector

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between li and .film_list. Your selector means that you have an element inside your li tag which contains the class 'film_list' instead of the li itself.